# Upload Song to SoundCloud via its api or API CONSOLE

Tags: soundcloud

I am developing an app for windows app store. I want to Upload Song to SoundCloud via its api or API CONSOLE. How to do it. I could not convert the audio file into binary data

i am using this code for Windows 8 app

```
WinJS.xhr({

                    url: "https://api.soundcloud.com/me/tracks.json?client_id=ID",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {

                        title: "UploadingTesting",
                        asset_data: audioBinary

                    },
                }).done(function (request) {
                    var responseJSON = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                }, function (err) {
                    console.log(err.responseText);
                });
```

Comment: Nobody can help you with this little information. Which language are you developing in?

Comment: Where does the variable audioBinary come from, are you using the Windows.Storage.FileIO.readBufferAsync(file).done( /* Your success and error handlers */ ) method from an audio file the user has already stored locally?

Comment: yeah exactly. i am using this method and audioBinary contains a binary data]

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I am trying to achieve the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

I've had limited success with posting JSON objects back to the SoundCloud API (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028893/soundcloud-api-unable-to-modify-web-profiles)), but from the structure of your jQuery you may need to change this to :

```
                    url: "https://api.soundcloud.com/me/tracks.json?client_id=ID",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: JSON,
                    data: {track:
                              {
                               title: "UploadingTesting",
                               asset_data: audioBinary
                              }
                           },
                }).done(function (request) {
                    var responseJSON = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                }).fail(function (err) {
                    console.log(err.responseText);
                });
```

Comment: Bro I have used this also But its giving me the Internal Server Error. I dont know what ami i doing wrong